# Django QuerySet: filter by the value of another field

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

I have a model I wish to filter by its attribute `a`. The model also has another attribute `b`. I am trying to filter entries where `a` is 0 or `a` has the value of the `b` attribute (for each row, obviously). How can I filter by the value of another column?

Here is what I have tried, and the missing piece:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(a=0) | Q(a=???)) # ??? is to be the value of the `b` column
```

I am using Django 1.4 and I know it is an old version that is no longer supported but unfortunately performing the upgrade is not up to me.

Comment: Do you have the option of changing your model?

Comment: F expression is available in 1.4, it is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you can use an [`F` expression](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.4/topics/db/queries.html#query-expressions) with your Q object:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(a=0) | Q(a=F('b')))
```

I'll also suggest you schedule your upgrade now, otherwise, you'll be missing out on other features and security fixes.

Comment: huh, for some reason I thought `F` expressions were introduced way mor recently. Thank you. As I mentioned, it is absolutely not up to me to upgrade, I wish it were.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the F model for comparing two fields.

```
from django.db.models import F
MyModel.objects.filter(a__exact = F('b'))
```

So for your joint query you can use something like,

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(a=0) | Q(a__exact=F('b')))
```

Comment: Does this check if the two values are the same?

Comment: Oh, you meant a has value equal to the b attribute, sorry it was not clear from your question, let me see what i can do.

Comment: Read the question carefully before answering.

Comment: Edited my answer, you should also make it clear what you mean in the question.